# How to make a popup panel that loads a webpage for like a survey in a .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, frames

What I’m trying to accomplish is this. I want it to be so that when the user clicks a button, a pop up comes up and allows them to complete, say, the survey. However, I do NOT want it to be a popup window, just something like in the image. Additionally, the pop up needs to be able to have a webpage embedded in it, because the survey is a page in itself. So basically, instead of it being that when the user clicks the button they are redirected, I want a pop up (not a popup window) to appear with the page in it. What I have used so far is iframe in a panel, but I feel there must be a better and more stable way, than using frames. Can anyone suggest a better method? Sorry about my terminology, if have no idea what this is called, I’m new to .ASP NET wed development.
Here is the code (the button changes visible=”False” to true):

```
   <asp:Panel CssClass="BlowItUp" ID="Panel1" runat="server" 
            Visible="False" >

         <iframe src="http://10.0.0.1/start.htm" style="width:100%; height:100%; top:0px;" />


      </asp:Panel>
```

The CSS if it matters:

```
.BlowItUp
{
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:90%;
    z-index:300;    
    right:10%;
    top:5%;
    padding:0px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have control over the "inner" page, I think a frame is the best you're going to manage. Otherwise the inner page will seek to navigate to another page and you'll lose your "framing".

The one thing I would suggest though is a different popup panel. Say [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "inner" please?

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I will look into your link. I will remember to accept your answer if it works. +1 for answering

Comment: So it looks to me like they are using frames too, just a different popup panel (for good reason). Right?

Comment: jQuery UI dialog doesn't use frames, it just pushes HTML around. It's just a prettier presentation and a bit cleaner than using a button to mark an asp:panel visible=true (presumably you're performing a postback to mark Panel1 as visible? jQuery UI dialog is entirely javascript driven, so you won't need a callback to the server to make the panel visible. *You will still need to use a frame to display the content of the other page*. Otherwise any navigation links within the page will move away from your "container" page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. THis should get me going!